# Navigate to specific section of page on clicking a list-group item

Tags: javascript, css, json, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a JSON similar to:

```
{
"qaset": [
  {
    "question": "question1",
    "answer": [
        "answer11",
        "answer12"
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "question2",
    "answer": "answer2"
  },
  {
    "question": "question1",
    "answer": [
        "answer31",
        "answer32"
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

On page 1, I have defined a list-group as follows:

```
<div class="list-group card">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-nav-item" ng-repeat="each in qaset">{{each.question}}</a>
</div>
```

Now, on clicking any of the item(i.e. question) from the list above, I want to be redirected to another page which has all "answer" from the JSON as various sections, but should just display the corresponding "answer" based on the item clicked from Page 1.

How do I define this page with all "answer"s as sections?
How do I move back and forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing two different pages, use angular UI router. It is easy and effective. You just need to add a click function to your anchor tag and pass the corresponding answer obj (i.e "each.answer"). inside the function body pass these params to the other view(page). You can get these values has stateparams in the next page. You need not plot all sections there.  make the other page as cacheable false. It will work. Incase your second page contains all the answers by default, then pass the question only from the first page and you can get, which answer to show.